# change only the color of the button clicked and the others return to the original color VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have 3 buttons, when I click on one of them, the other two would like them to go back to the original color

my html

```
       <div class="col-md-8 row gutter-sm opts">
          <q-btn 
            id='1'
            class="col-md-2 opt"
            label="OPTIONS 1"
            style="color: white"
            @click="filters(1);"
          />
          <q-btn 
            id='2'
            class="col-md-2 opt"
            label="OPTIONS 2"
            style="color: white"
            @click="filters(2);"
          />
          <q-btn 
            id='3'
            class="col-md-2 opt"
            label="OPTIONS 3"
            style="color: white"
            @click="filters(3);"
          />
       </div>
```

my JS

```
   methods: {
      filters(id){
         var select = id
         document.getElementsByClassName("opt").style.backgroundColor="white"
         document.getElementById(select).style.backgroundColor='black'
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have VUE, you should not try and manipulate the DOM yourself.

Add a data variable "selected" and store say the id of the selected button

ON render, bind the style property to a computed and you can set the style based on the selected property of the data property.

For your button do something like this:

```html
<button :style="[selected===1 ? {'background': '#333'}: {'background': '#FFF'}]">
```

and then store selected in the data so your method only sets the `selected = id`

Comment: Can essentially make the ternary condition on the inside of the background too. ^^

Comment: Yes, indeed, but I opted for this way in case other parameters needed to be added

Comment: @Christian Guimarães did this solve your issue? Can you mark it as answer please?